# How to mock values returned from the sample function within pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to unit test a function that calls panda's sample function.  It looks like this:

`return df.col_of_interest.sample(35, random_state=111).sum()`

How can I mock the values that will be sampled from the dataframe so that I can set an expected value for the unit test?

Comment: do you want to test the data or the function?

Comment: if just the function, you may be better off creating dataframe as a fixture, something like `df = pd.read_dict(my_fixture_dict)`

Comment: I just want to test the function.  I have set the dataframe as a fixture already but since there are more than 35 rows in the dataframe, I can't know which rows the sampling function will return.

Comment: `df.col_of_interest.sample(35, random_state=111)` should return the same df sample every time.  If you want to compare what that will be, run it once and get the sampled output